# Multiple Combo Boxes with shared Binding - Display error after first selection from box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I've been stumped on an issue I've run across in the last few days now and would like some help figuring it out.

I'm developing a WPF application that on its first run will prompt the user to manually assign detected serial ports to arbitrary 'channels', used throughout the application and later interface for displaying data etc.

One of the key features is once a port has been assigned in a combo box, it is then no longer available for selection in the others (using the .IsEnabled Property of the ComboBoxItem Class).

The issue I've run into is that while initially everything works fine - each combo box is set, opening the next sees the previous selection greyed out - **if I attempt to go back to a combo box I've previously set it displays an empty drop down**. It looks as if the drop-down is still active but that the window that contains the items hasn't been sized properly.

Screen Captures:

[Items are successfully disabled in subsequent combo boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g4Zp.png)

[Returning to an already selected box results in a blank drop down (blue circle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVIVZ.png)

Here's my XAML code for the combo boxes:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Name="ComboPanel" Margin="5, 20, 5, 5">
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel0"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel1"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel2"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel3"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel4"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel5"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel6"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel7"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel8"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel9"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel10" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
            <ComboBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Width="100" Height="25" Name="cboxChannel11" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="false" ItemsSource="{Binding portCollectionItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" DropDownOpened="CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed" />
        </StackPanel>
```

And here's the behind code snippets relevant to the boxes:

```
public partial class PortWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> portCollectionItems { get; set; }
    public ComboBoxItem selectedItem;
    public bool serialPortsSet { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxItem SelectedItem 
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set 
        { 
            if (selectedItem == value) 
                return;

            selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
        }
    }
    public PortWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext    = this;
        serialPortsSet = false;
        portCollectionItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ActiveSerialPorts.DetectedPorts.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) 
            {
                portCollectionItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "<-Select->" });
            }

            portCollectionItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = ActiveSerialPorts.DetectedPorts[i] }); // Populates collection with a list of serial port names from another class 
        }
    }

    void CboxChannel0_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox     = sender as ComboBox;
        string selectedString = comboBox.SelectionBoxItem as string;
        selectedItem          = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;

        foreach (ComboBoxItem portItems in portCollectionItems) 
        {
            if (portItems.Content == selectedItem.Content) 
            {
                portItems.IsEnabled = true; //re-enables the previously disabled selection in case the assigned port needs changing
            }
        }
    }

    void CboxChannel0_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        selectedItem      = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        string itemString = selectedItem.Content.ToString();

        if (!itemString.Contains("<-Select->"))
        {
            foreach (ComboBoxItem portItems in portCollectionItems) 
            {
                if (portItems.Content == selectedItem.Content) 
                {
                    portItems.IsEnabled = false; // disables the selected item in the observable collection 
                    return;
                }
            }  
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I'm inclined to believe there's something small but vital I'm missing with regards to the binding. I originally thought it was the altering of a property within a shared collection that was causing the problem, but after supressing all of the code in the handlers and running it the issue persisted.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should never have collections of UI elements, unless maybe if you write a custom control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sharing ComboBoxItems among different ComboBoxes. Those are visual elements and you're trying to share them among different parents. I'm not surprised it breaks.

You need each ComboBox to have a distinct collection of ComboBoxItem instances. You can most simply do that by exposing your items as `ObservableCollection<String>` and letting each ComboBox create its own ComboBoxItems. Bind the collection the same way you're binding the collection you've got; I think that declaring and populating that collection should almost  be the only change you need to make, unless you need to disable port items for *all* boxes at once, rather than just the one they were selected in. Your `SelectedItem` on the combobox will be the string, though, rather than `ComboBoxItem, so the guts of those loops will have to change a bit.

When you disable a ComboBoxItem, it will be disabled only for the ComboBox it belongs to, naturally. If you want `COM4` disabled for all boxes, you'll have to do that in a loop.

Or you could go a little more MVVM: If this were me, I would create the series of ComboBoxes in a templated ItemsControl bound to a collection of some class that had a SelectedPort property, and I would use a custom class for the items as well, just a simple thing with `String PortName` and `bool IsPortEnabled`. I'd bind `IsPortEnabled` to `ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled` in the XAML. There'd be a lot less code, but it's a big jump conceptually from where you're at now. We can go there if you're interested.

Comment: Well you were absolutely right. Made a quick change creating separate  ObservableCollections for each and it seems fine. Unfortunately a disabled selection needs to be disabled for all the combo boxes, as in by selecting one for one channel it is no longer an option in any of the others. If it wasn't so time sensitive a project I'd be happy to take you up on your help with the latter suggestion - I'm fairly new to programming in languages more complicated than Excel VB. Is there a tutorial perhaps somewhere you could point me towards for future reference?

Comment: @PSetters I keep meaning to write one. I haven't found one I like. I got a basic grounding years ago from a [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com) Silverlight course (employer paid for it). My girlfriend speaks very highly of Lynda.com for PHP and web stuff, and LinkedIn has recently been spamming me with offers of a free month of lynda.com membership, not sure if that's still a live offer.