# Dynamic binding multiple comboboxes to disable selected sourceitems

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

This is my first post... so I hope I do it right.  I am using C#, WPF, and trying to follow the MVVM pattern.  Admittedly, I have a lot to learn, but have been making progress in the last year.  I would appreciate any other comments on the code I post to help me learn also.

**The goal: Bind the sourceitems of multiple (3 to 5) comboboxes to the same observable collection with the requirement that any item in the observable collection is used only once.  If an item is selected in one combobox, this item would be disabled for all other comboboxes**

**Research:**  In my searching, I have come across two posts:

> [C# multiple combobox with the same itemssource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885812/c-sharp-multiple-combobox-with-the-same-itemssource)
>
> You should have a look at the MVVM pattern and ICollectionView. It's easy to achive but hard to explain when you don't know at least MVVM. – Mighty Badaboom Jul 3 '17 at 12:42
>
> [Multiple Combo Boxes with shared Binding - Display error after first selection from box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329394/multiple-combo-boxes-with-shared-binding-display-error-after-first-selection-f)
>
> Or you could go a little more MVVM: If this were me, I would create the series of ComboBoxes in a templated ItemsControl bound to a collection of some class that had a SelectedPort property, and I would use a custom class for the items as well, just a simple thing with String PortName and bool IsPortEnabled. I'd bind IsPortEnabled to ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled in the XAML. There'd be a lot less code, but it's a big jump conceptually from where you're at now. We can go there if you're interested -- Jul 12 '16 at 13:27 Ed Plunkett

One of the answers above to MVVM was not outlined or requested by the individual who posted the question.  I am interested in "taking the big jump conceptually" to learn how to do this elegantly.

**UI Function:**  The application that I am writing takes input from the user to  perform an analysis of topographic feature break lines of different types.  There are 2 modes of analysis (two radio buttons) that require different inputs (groupbox for feature selection enabled / disabled).

Now, I have up to 5 comboboxes that are bound to the same observable collection for the source items.  The "Feature0" combobox is required for analysis mode1 or mode2, with Feature1 to Feature3 comboboxes and optionally Feature4 combobox (for mode1).

Now, with this background, the requirement is that the any item in the observable collection can only be used once for Feature0-4 comboboxes, or for Feature0 and Feature5-6 comboboxes (see image [WPF UI Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNt5o.png)).  I am not sure how to take the group of enabled comboboxes and when any one of them changes, get the selected item and disable that source item from the other comboboxes.

**For example**, if "Layer_0" is selected in the "Feature0" combobox, "Layer_0" sourceitem in Feature1-4 comboboxes should be disabled so the user is unable to select this item in other comboboxes.

**Here are the items that I think need to be done:**

1. Event handler for combobox_SelectedIndexChanged - binding to comboboxes in FeaturesView.xaml, and in FeaturesViewModel.cs.  *Can one event event handler can be used (still researching)?*
2. How to maintain sourceitem list of selected items for the enabled controls and disable all selected items from the sourceitem list?

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Code Files Below** - You will find below the different project files that I have so far with the UI working.  Obviously, the part that doesn't work is disabling selected feature names.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Views"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="300"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <views:FeatureView />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**FeatureView.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApp1.Views.FeatureView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyRadioButtonTemplate" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboWithHeader" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Target="comboBox" />

                <ComboBox
                    x:Name="comboBox"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="2"
                    IsEnabled="True"
                    IsTabStop="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Features, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">

            <GroupBox Header="Analysis Mode">
                <Grid Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton
                        x:Name="Mode1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Content="Mode 1"
                        IsChecked="True"
                        Style="{StaticResource MyRadioButtonTemplate}" />

                    <RadioButton
                        x:Name="Mode2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Content="Mode2"
                        Style="{StaticResource MyRadioButtonTemplate}" />

                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>

            <GroupBox Header="Line Selection">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentControl
                        Name="Feature0"
                        Content="Feature 0"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}" />
                    <Button
                        Width="60"
                        Margin="5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Content="Select" />

                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>

            <GroupBox
                Header="Mode1 Layer Names"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Mode1, Path=IsChecked}"
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Mode1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentControl
                        Name="Feature1"
                        Content="Feature 1"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}" />
                    <ContentControl
                        Name="Feature2"
                        Content="Feature 2"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}" />
                    <ContentControl
                        Name="Feature3"
                        Content="Feature 3"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}" />
                    <ContentControl
                        Name="Feature4"
                        Content="Feature 4"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}"
                        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=IncludeFeature4, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
                    <CheckBox
                        Name="IncludeFeature4"
                        Margin="2"
                        Content="Include Feature 4" />
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>

            <GroupBox
                Header="Mode2 Layer Names"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Mode2, Path=IsChecked}"
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Mode2, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentControl
                        Name="Feature5"
                        Content="Feature 5"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}" />
                    <ContentControl
                        Name="Feature6"
                        Content="Feature 6"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}" />

                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**FeatureView.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApp1.Views
{
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using WpfApp1.ViewModels;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MultiComboBoxes.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FeatureView : UserControl
    {
        public FeatureView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new FeatureViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**FeatureModel.cs**

```
namespace WpfApp1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public class FeatureModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private enum FeatureList
        {
            Layer_0,
            Layer_1,
            Layer_2,
            Layer_3,
            Layer_4,
            Layer_5,
            Layer_6
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Features = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enum.GetNames(typeof(FeatureList)));

        private string featureName;

        public string FeatureName
        {
            get
            {
                return featureName;
            }

            set
            {
                if (featureName != value)
                {
                    featureName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FeatureName");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FeatureViewModel.cs**

```
namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using WpfApp1.Models;

    public class FeatureViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> AllFeatures { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Features { get; set; }

        public FeatureViewModel()
        {
            FeatureModel featureModel = new FeatureModel();
            Features = featureModel.Features;
            AllFeatures = Features;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Need to implement this interface in order to get data binding
        /// to work properly.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want them to cascade? I.E. pick the first one and that sets up the second combobox for selection?

Comment: Are you saying if "Layer_1" is selected for "Feature 1" then "Layer 1" should not even be a selectable option for "Feature 2"?

Comment: I dont think they need to cascade - if this means that comboxes must be selected in a certain order, Feature1 then Feature2, etc.  @Nick, yes, you are correct.  if "Layer_1" is selected in "Feature1", the sourceitems for all other enabled comboboxes in this example should be disabled.

Comment: Based on that, I don't think you can use the same collection as the source for all of the comboboxes. I think you'll need to use a different collection for each one and whenever a selection is made, remove the new selection from the collections for the other comboboxes and re-add the previous selection to them.

Comment: BTW you don't need to create your own `BoolToVisibilityConverter`. There already is a standard `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` in `System.Windows.Controls`

Comment: Thx.  I just learned something new and reduced some coding.  Made the change as suggested and it worked.

Comment: Nick, I did as suggested and added a observable collection for each combobox.  I ran into another problem... since I am using a controltemplate for the label/combobox, I can't find a way to bind the individual variables to the combobox without eliminating the control template.  Is there a way to do this or maybe a better way to define my control template?

Comment: Does anyone have an example of how I could implement binding 3 comboboxes to the same observable collection and only allow an observable item to be selected once.  Once it has been selected in a combobox, the other comboboxes would reflect that change by disabling the item(s) that are already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and more researching online, I am posting a partial solution to my question.  Maybe it will help someone else in the future.

The solution differs from question the original question in how I wanted to implement it; however, it does provide a workable solution.  The main problem that I see with this implementation is that it requires what I think is redundant code if more comboboxes are added.

**Implementation Changes:**

1. Radio button to select analysis modes - not relevant to the basic question of binding
2. Disabling items - While this would have been nice, removing the item from the list was easier for now.
3. Binding multiple comboboxes to a single observable collection was replaced by an IEnumerable of sourceitems for each combobox.
4. Added a button next to each combobox to "clear" the selected item.

I am certain there is a better and more *MVVM'ish* way of doing this (which was my hope of finding by posting this question), but after a lot of researching and reading many topics online to try to figure it out, I was unsuccessful due to my lack of expertise.  Maybe someone with expertise can modify this solution properly.

**Below is the code that is working with four comboboxes.**  There is one item that doesn't work as I would want.  An Empty list item is used as, but when removing selected items from each list, the empty item should be ignored (still figuring out a solution for this).

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Properties"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Views"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="350"
    Height="700"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <views:FeatureView />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

FeatureView.xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApp1.Views.FeatureView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <!--  MyComboBoxStyle  -->
        <Style x:Key="MyComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Margin="2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                                Foreground="Black"
                                IsTabStop="False" />

                            <ComboBox
                                Name="cmbBox"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="2"
                                Foreground="Black"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedItem}" />

                            <Button
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Padding="2"
                                Command="{Binding OnComboBox_ClearSelection}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cmbBox}"
                                Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonTemplate}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--  MyButtonTemplate  -->
        <Style x:Key="MyButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border
                                Name="border"
                                Padding="4,2"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="3">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock Text="X"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>

        <!--  MyLabelTemplate  -->
        <Style x:Key="MyLabelTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        </Style>

        <!--  MyTextBlockTemplate  -->
        <Style x:Key="MyTextBlockTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>


    <!--  Main Layout  -->
    <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">

        <!--  Feature 1  -->
        <ComboBox
            Name="Feature1View"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Feature1Items}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Feature1SelectedValue}"
            Style="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}"
            Tag="Feature 1" />

        <!--  Feature 2  -->
        <ComboBox
            Name="Feature2View"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Feature2Items}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Feature2SelectedValue}"
            Style="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}"
            Tag="Feature 2" />


        <!--  Feature 3  -->
        <ComboBox
            Name="Feature3View"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Feature3Items}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Feature3SelectedValue}"
            Style="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}"
            Tag="Feature 3" />

        <!--  Feature 4  -->
        <ComboBox
            Name="Feature4View"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Feature4Items}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Feature4SelectedValue}"
            Style="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}"
            Tag="Feature 4" />

        <Rectangle
            Width="Auto"
            Height="5"
            Fill="#FFF4F4F5"
            Stroke="Black" />

        <!--  Feature 1 Selected  -->
        <DockPanel>
            <Label Content="Feature 1 Selected" Style="{StaticResource MyLabelTemplate}" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="Feature1Selected"
                Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockTemplate}"
                Text="{Binding Feature1SelectedValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!--  Feature 2 Selected  -->
        <DockPanel>
            <Label Content="Feature 2 Selected" Style="{StaticResource MyLabelTemplate}" />

            <TextBlock
                x:Name="Feature2Selected"
                Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockTemplate}"
                Text="{Binding Feature2SelectedValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!--  Feature 3 Selected  -->
        <DockPanel>
            <Label Content="Feature 3 Selected" Style="{StaticResource MyLabelTemplate}" />

            <TextBlock
                x:Name="Feature3Selected"
                Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockTemplate}"
                Text="{Binding Feature3SelectedValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!--  Feature 4 Selected  -->
        <DockPanel>
            <Label Content="Feature 4 Selected" Style="{StaticResource MyLabelTemplate}" />

            <TextBlock
                x:Name="Feature4Selected"
                Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockTemplate}"
                Text="{Binding Feature4SelectedValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DockPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

FeatureView.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApp1.Views
{
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using WpfApp1.ViewModels;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MultiComboBoxes.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FeatureView : UserControl
    {
        public FeatureView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new FeatureViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

FeatureViewModel.cs:

```
namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using WpfApp1.Models;

    public class FeatureViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Definitions

        #region enum

        private enum MyFeatureList
        {
            Layer_1,
            Layer_2,
            Layer_3,
            Layer_4
        }

        #endregion enum

        #region PrivateProperties

        private readonly List<string> features = new List<string>();

        #region AddFeatures

        private ObservableCollection<Feature> AddFeatures
        {
            get
            {
                var features = new ObservableCollection<Feature>
            {
                // add blank feature
                new Feature("", true)
            };
                foreach (var feature in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyFeatureList)))
                {
                    features.Add(new Feature(feature, true));
                }
                return features;
            }
        }

        #endregion AddFeatures

        #endregion PrivateProperties

        #region PublicProperties

        public IEnumerable<string> Feature1Items => features.Where(o => o != Feature2SelectedValue && o != Feature3SelectedValue && o != Feature4SelectedValue);

        public IEnumerable<string> Feature2Items => features.Where(o => o != Feature1SelectedValue && o != Feature3SelectedValue && o != Feature4SelectedValue);

        public IEnumerable<string> Feature3Items => features.Where(o => o != Feature1SelectedValue && o != Feature2SelectedValue && o != Feature4SelectedValue);

        public IEnumerable<string> Feature4Items => features.Where(o => o != Feature1SelectedValue && o != Feature2SelectedValue && o != Feature3SelectedValue);

        #endregion PublicProperties

        #region Constructor

        public FeatureViewModel()
        {
            features = AddFeatures.Select(c => c.FeatureName).ToList();
            OnComboBox_ClearSelection = new BaseCommand(ClearSelection);
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Feature1SelectedValue

        protected string feature1SelectedValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Feature 1 selected value
        /// </summary>
        public string Feature1SelectedValue
        {
            get { return feature1SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                if (feature1SelectedValue != value)
                {
                    feature1SelectedValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature2Items));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature3Items));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature4Items));
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Feature1SelectedValue

        #region Feature2SelectedValue

        protected string feature2SelectedValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Feature 1 selected value
        /// </summary>
        public string Feature2SelectedValue
        {
            get { return feature2SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                if (feature2SelectedValue != value)
                {
                    feature2SelectedValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature1Items));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature3Items));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature4Items));
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Feature2SelectedValue

        #region Feature3SelectedValue

        protected string feature3SelectedValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Feature 1 selected value
        /// </summary>
        public string Feature3SelectedValue
        {
            get { return feature3SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                if (feature3SelectedValue != value)
                {
                    feature3SelectedValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature1Items));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature2Items));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature4Items));
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Feature3SelectedValue

        #region Feature4SelectedValue

        protected string feature4SelectedValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Feature 1 selected value
        /// </summary>
        public string Feature4SelectedValue
        {
            get { return feature4SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                if (feature4SelectedValue != value)
                {
                    feature4SelectedValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature1Items));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature2Items));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Feature3Items));
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Feature4SelectedValue

        #endregion Definitions

        #region Methods

        public ICommand OnComboBox_ClearSelection { get; }

        public void ClearSelection(object sender)
        {
            ComboBox combobox = sender as ComboBox;
            combobox.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        #endregion Methods

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Need to implement this interface in order to get data binding
        /// to work properly.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    }

    #region BaseCommand

    public class BaseCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _method;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public BaseCommand(Action<object> method)
            : this(method, null)
        {
        }

        public BaseCommand(Action<object> method, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _method = method;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _method.Invoke(parameter);
        }

        #endregion BaseCommand
    }
}
```

Features.cs:

```
namespace WpfApp1.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public class Feature : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Feature()
        {
        }

        public Feature(string featureName, bool isSelected)
        {
            this.featureName = featureName;
            this.isSelected = isSelected;
        }

        private string featureName;

        public string FeatureName
        {
            get
            {
                return featureName;
            }

            set
            {
                if (featureName != value)
                {
                    featureName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FeatureName");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return isSelected;
            }

            set
            {
                if (isSelected != value)
                {
                    isSelected = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```